Strange scrolling behavior on ios mobile
I have a three.js landing page on my WordPress site. Once the animation stops the user swipes right or left. On that view the user is to swipe up or down to scroll, this is where we are experiencing some strange behavior. On android mobile the swipe up and down to scroll works fine. On ios mobile, you cannot initially swipe down (the page refreshes rather than scrolls). You can, however, swipe up and scrolling works as normal. Strangely, once you swipe up, swipe down then begins working. Any help on fixing this issue would be appreciated. site is https://everyrep.com
I set these to the scroll container with no luck:
      overscroll-behavior-x: none;
      overscroll-behavior-y: none;

